# fwupd-refresh.service fails periodically when running from systemd 12 hours

Tags: server, systemd, vmware

Manual execution is success. Nothings happen.

```
Jul 30 19:28:02 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Jul 31 07:27:59 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Aug 01 18:43:00 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Aug 02 06:13:04 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.


/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh --force
WARNING: UEFI firmware can not be updated in legacy BIOS mode
  See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:legacy-bios for more information.
Updating lvfs
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Successfully downloaded new metadata: 0 local devices supported

Journal:
Jul 23 07:12:00 server fwupdmgr[1437081]: Updating lvfs
Jul 23 07:12:00 server fwupdmgr[1437081]: Downloading…: 0%
Jul 23 07:13:00 server fwupdmgr[1437081]: Idle…: 0%
Jul 23 07:13:00 server systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL>
```

Config does not shows any different:

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service
[Unit]
Description=Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
Documentation=man:fwupdmgr(1)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
CacheDirectory=fwupdmgr
StandardError=null
ProtectSystem=strict
ProtectHome=read-only
User=fwupd-refresh
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_NETLINK AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
SystemCallFilter=~@mount
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
SuccessExitStatus=2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh
```

Ubuntu:
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

fwupd version:
runtime   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9

Any suggestions? There are many topics for fwupd but thoise are related to older versions.